# forecasting imputed data

Tags: forecasting, arima, multiple-imputation

My data set consists of a 15 year time series of monthly water quality measurements (10 different measurements). The data set has ~30% missingness. I applied multiple imputation using the Amelia II package, and imputed 10 data sets. I want to forecast several of these variables separately using ARIMA models. My question is, for any given variable of interest, if I fit an ARIMA model to each of the 10 imputed data sets, and average the models using Rubin's rules to create a single model, if I want to forecast values using the combined model, what data do I forecast on? In other words, once I have a combined model and want to use it for forecasting, which of the 10 data sets do I then use as a basis to calculate future values? Should I average the values of the 10 sets and apply the combined model to that?

Comment: I understand that you had one data set with missing values. You then produced 10 data sets by imputing different values. If all the 10 imputations are equally likely, I would fit an ARIMA model to each of the 10 data sets and forecast using that model, then average out forecasts to obtain the final forecast. If the 10 imputations are not equally likely but you have estimates of their relative probabilities, take a probability-weighted average.